# Pandas, convert datetime format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

The default format of csv is dd/mm/yyyy. When I convert it to datetime by `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`, it change the format to mm//dd/yyyy.

Then, I used `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`
 to convert to dd/mm/yyyy, But, they are in the string (object) format. However, I need to change them to `datetime` format. When I use again this (`df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`), it gets back to the previous format. Need your help

Comment: No, in python it is not possible, if want datetimes objects.

Comment: So, how to solve the problem, if I want the new format?

Comment: have you tried the `format` parameter of `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: @MohitMotwani, yes, but no difference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `parse_dates` and `dayfirst` arguments of `pd.read_csv`, see: [the docs for read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

This will read the `Date` column as datetime values, correctly taking the first part of the date input as the day. Note that in general you will want your dates to be stored as datetime objects.

Then, if you need to output the dates as a string you can call `dt.strftime()`:

```
df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: nope, this doesnt work - ARGHHH python is frustrating.

Comment: If your file has mm/dd/yy then set dayfirst to False

Answer (score 1):

> When I use again this: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`, it gets back to the previous format.

**No**, you cannot simultaneously have the string format of your choice and keep your series of type `datetime`. As remarked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52027599/9209546):

> `datetime` series are stored internally as integers. Any
>   human-readable date representation is just that, a *representation*,
>   not the underlying integer. To access your custom formatting, you can
>   use methods available in Pandas. You can even store such a text
>   representation in a `pd.Series` variable:
>
> ```
> formatted_dates = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
> ```
>
> The `dtype` of `formatted_dates` will be `object`, which indicates
>   that the elements of your series point to arbitrary Python times. In
>   this case, those arbitrary types happen to be all strings.
>
> Lastly, I strongly recommend you do *not* convert a `datetime` series
>   to strings until the very last step in your workflow. This is because
>   as soon as you do so, you will no longer be able to use efficient,
>   vectorised operations on such a series.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for all cases where a column has mixed date formats. Add more conditions to the function if needed. Pandas to_datetime() function was not working for me, but this seems to work well.

```
import date
def format(val):
    a = pd.to_datetime(val, errors='coerce', cache=False).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    try:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y')
    except:
        date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y')
    return date_time_obj.date()
```

Saving the changes to the same column.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: format(x))
```

Saving as CSV.

```
df.to_csv(f'{file_name}.csv', index=False, date_format='%s')
```